# group by Date in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an array of birthdays

```
const birthdays = [
    {name: 'John', birthday: '08-08-1960'},
    {name: 'James', birthday: '08-25-1960'},
    {name: 'Mary', birthday: '01-01-1990'},
]
```

and I need to generate a new array with the birthdays grouped by *month-year*

```
const grouped = [
    {'08-1960': [
        {name: 'John', birthday: '08-08-1960'},
        {name: 'James', birthday: '08-25-1960'},        
    ]},
    {'01-1990': [
        {name: 'Mary', birthday: '01-01-1990'}, 
    ]},
]
```

I was looking at something like this. using *moment* and *lodash*

```
let groupedResults = _.groupBy(results, (result) => moment(result['Date'], 'DD/MM/YYYY').startOf('isoWeek'));
```

but I can´t imagine how to generate the new array structure (with the month-year as keys) thank you.

**update:** it should return an array not an object :facepalm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `reduce()`

- Apply `reduce()` on array of object and set accumulator to empty object `{}`
- Then `split()` birthday by `-` and get only get first and third element.
- If the key exist is accumulator that `concat()` new value to it. Otherwise `concat()` it to empty array `[]` and then set it as property of accumulator.

```js
const arr = [
    {name: 'John', birthday: '08-08-1960'},
    {name: 'James', birthday: '08-25-1960'},
    {name: 'John', birthday: '01-01-1990'},
]

let res = arr.reduce((ac,a) => {
 let key = a.birthday.split('-');
 key = `${key[0]}-${key[2]}`;
 ac[key] = (ac[key] || []).concat(a);
 return ac;
},{})
res = Object.entries(res).map(([k,v]) => ({[k]:v}))
console.log(res)
```

Comment: I´m confused. this is returning an object. I think I explained it in the wrong way. it should return an array  (updating now)

Comment: @handsome I have updated the answer please check it.

Comment: I see it working with the updated code thanks!! any chance to make it work with full dates as birthdat? like 2019-05-18 21:09:03

Comment: @handsome For that don't use `let key = a.birthday.split('-');
 key = `${key[0]}-${key[2]}`;`. Just simply use `let key = a.birthday`

Comment: I fixed it with let key = moment(a.birthday).format('MM-YYYY'); thank you so much you saved the night :)

Comment: hey @Maheer Ali if you are still around. it is returning me: 0 > 08-1960: [...]. how to get rid of the index? just like I put it in the description. thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

As explained here https://www.dyn-web.com/javascript/arrays/associative.php you can create arrays where the indexes are strings, but i won't work as a normal array.

Here is a snippet for doing what you want.

```js
    const birthdays = [
        {name: 'John', birthday: '08-08-1960'},
        {name: 'James', birthday: '08-25-1960'},
        {name: 'Mary', birthday: '01-01-1990'},
    ];

    const grouped = birthdays.reduce((prev, cur) => {

     const date = new Date(cur.birthday);
     const key = `${(date.getMonth() + 1)}-${date.getFullYear()}`;

     if(!prev[key]){
      prev[key] = [ cur ];
        }
     else{
      prev[key].push(cur);
        }

     return prev;
    }, []);

    for(let i in grouped){
      console.log(grouped[i]);
    }
```

Comment: You can remove the else condition if you change `if(!prev[key]){
      prev[key] = [];
        }`