# how to filter data in specific days

Tags: javascript, filter

I have some data like these:

```
[
  {
    startTime: '2020-01-28T11:00:00',
    name: 'John',
  },
  {
    startTime: '2020-01-28T12:00:00',
    name: 'Doe'
  },
  {
    startTime: '2020-01-29T10:00:00',
    name: 'javascript',
  }
]
```

As you see I got same days in some objects and now I want to filter them by day! All the same days be into an array.

Be like this:

```
[
  {
    startTime: '2020-01-28T11:00:00',
    name: 'John'
  },
  {
    startTime: '2020-01-28T12:00:00',
    name: 'Doe'
  },
],
[
  {
    startTime: '2020-01-29T10:00:00',
    name: 'javascript'
  },
]
```

Do you have any suggestion or advice?

Comment: @JeremyHarris Yes I did. but I couldn't find relative answer due to my question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46802448/how-do-i-group-items-in-an-array-by-date/46802505

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56204489/group-by-date-in-javascript

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `groupBy` function like this for the same

We group `players` by substring of first 10 characters in `startTime` which will be the data of same

```js
var players = [
    {
      startTime: '2020-01-28T11:00:00',
      name: 'John',
    },
    {
      startTime: '2020-01-28T12:00:00',
      name: 'Doe'
    },
    {
      startTime: '2020-01-29T10:00:00',
      name: 'javascript',
    }
  ]
  
  var groupBy = function(xs, key) {
    return xs.reduce(function(rv, x) {
      (rv[x[key].substr(0,10)] = rv[x[key].substr(0,10)] || []).push(x);
      return rv;
    }, {});
  };
  
  console.log(Object.values(groupBy(players, 'startTime')));
```